# DIV not displaying all JSON retrieved data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html, html-framework-7

Why is this code not displaying all the data. It cuts off the display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://xxxxxxx/integration/json_news.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var source = field.source;
                var summary = field.summary;
                var heading = field.heading;
                var news_date = field.news_date;
                $("#newsview").append("<tr class='even gradeA' width = '30px'><td><li><b>"+heading+" - "+news_date+"</b> <br />"+summary+"</i></li><br /></td></tr>");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the DIV I am calling the ajax code.

```
<!--NEWS PAGE -->
                <div data-page="news" class="page cached">
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <div id="newsview"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am using `IntelXDK` and building a `Framework7` hybrid application

Somehow I can figure out why this is so when I test on the mobile phone. Could it be that `Framework7` doesnot display data beyond certain size? Or my code is faulty somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your js-generated HTML is not valid.

You're appending table rows `tr` to `div`. They also contain `li`.

`tr` should be a child node of `table` and `li` should be a child node of `ul` or `ol`.

Also `width = '30px'` should be without spaces: `width='30px'`.
BTW, do you really want so narrow container for your content?

And you have closing `</i>` tag which does not have open `<i>` before.

I suggest the following:

```
$("#newsview").append(
   '<div class="even gradeA"><b>'+
    heading+ ' - ' +news_date+ 
   '</b><br><i>' +summary+ '</i></div>'
 );
```

And then use CSS to style it.